# How to completely remove app from iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

There is an app called X in my iPhone which can tell you whether or not you have installed other apps before in this iPhone.

Then I installed an app A into my iPhone, and app X tells me A has not been installed before.

Then I uninstalled app A and then reinstalled it, and app X tells me A has been installed before.

How does X know that A has been installed or not?

And how can I completely remove app A and let app X tells me A has not been installed?

I have jailbreaked my iPhone, is there any app can do that?

Comment: Try installing X, installing A then remove A and X and re-install X and A.  I bet it tells you that A hasn't been installed before

Comment: I have tried, but X still tells A has been installed. It seems that iOS can record which app has been installed before?

Comment: My guess would be that they are examining URLs registered by apps.  Is app X only available on jailbroken devices?

Comment: No, X is an apple store app. I jailbreak it trying to find out which files are changed after install and uninstall an app. But have no clue.

Comment: The my guess is they scan for known app URLs (such as Facebook://) and record this information.  If they store it on a server or in iCloud or in keychain then they can restore this information if X is reinstalled

Comment: you mean app X scans for known app URLs? If I reset iPhone, and install X and A, X will tell me that A has not been installed before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65894/discussion-between-paulw11-and-sato).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understand what you are asking for. But if you are asking, how X is doing what you described, here is my guess:

If your iPhone is jailbreaked, every app can have full access to the file system. There is nothing on your phone the app can't find.

Under these circumstances, it is pretty easy to check if an app has already been installed:
Each app is installed in a path with a unique id. This id, however, changes with every reinstall (and maybe even if you update the app). What doesn't change is the bundle identifier in the app inside the app's info.plist. This means, if you see the same bundle identifier in two different folders over time, the app has been installed multiple times.

If app X is running in the background that is even easier: If the folder of app A is removed, the app has been uninstalled. As the phone is jailbreaked, app X can constantly check this.